# SQL query not working for some reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

i'm writing this query for a leaderboard system.  It needs to return the next closest target for the person in relation to the targets score.  For some reason my sql query just won't work.

This is my query:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Children WHERE Completed > '%d' OR ( Completed = '%d' AND 'Current Stickers' > '%d')",completecount,completecount, stickercount];
```

completecount = the amount of times this person has completed the goal
stickercount = the amount of stickers this person has.
both are ints
So i want the query to return people who have completed it more than the person or if its the same amount of times and if they have more stickers than them.

database layout:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@' ('%@'"
                 "TEXT PRIMARY KEY, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' TEXT, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' INTEGER);", tableName, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11];
```

field names:

```
[self createTable:@"Children" withField1:@"Name" withField2:@"Password" withField3:@"House" withField4:@"Sticker Collection" withField5:@"Tickets Gathered" withField6:@"Tickets Removed" withField7:@"Last Ticket Scanned" withField8:@"Current Tickets" withField9:@"Completed" withField10:@"Complete" withField11:@"Current Stickers"];
```

This is the actual query:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(Childdb, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
          char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
          NSString *field1Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field1];
        char *field2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8);
        NSString *field2Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];
        char *field3 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10);
        NSString *field3Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field3];
          NSLog(@"Name:%@",field1Str);
        NSLog(@"this is completecount: %@", field2Str);
        NSLog(@"this is stickcount: %@",field3Str);
```

So the real problem is that despite the query set up its still returning invalid records.  Looks at this example:

This persons name is stuart:

```
2013-02-24 16:35:55.409 TableViewStory[15672:907] stickercount = 3
2013-02-24 16:35:55.410 TableViewStory[15672:907] completecount = 0
2013-02-24 16:35:55.412 TableViewStory[15672:907] Name:Oliver
2013-02-24 16:35:55.413 TableViewStory[15672:907] this is completecount: 1
2013-02-24 16:35:55.414 TableViewStory[15672:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 16:35:55.415 TableViewStory[15672:907] Name:Rupert
2013-02-24 16:35:55.416 TableViewStory[15672:907] this is completecount: 2
2013-02-24 16:35:55.417 TableViewStory[15672:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 16:35:55.418 TableViewStory[15672:907] Name:Emily
2013-02-24 16:35:55.419 TableViewStory[15672:907] this is completecount: 0
2013-02-24 16:35:55.420 TableViewStory[15672:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 16:35:55.421 TableViewStory[15672:907] Name:Stuart
2013-02-24 16:35:55.423 TableViewStory[15672:907] this is completecount: 0
2013-02-24 16:35:55.424 TableViewStory[15672:907] this is stickcount: 3
```

Check this out, its even showing himself in the results ^ here.  not only that its even showing Emily which has the same complete count but not more stickers than Stuart, yet Emily is still retrieved.  Whats going on here?

Request by Ege Akpinar to remove part of the where clause:

```
  NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Children WHERE Completed > %d",completecount];
```

results:

```
2013-02-24 17:37:22.626 TableViewStory[15814:907] This is the sticker count: 4
2013-02-24 17:37:22.627 TableViewStory[15814:907] This is the complete count: 0
2013-02-24 17:37:22.629 TableViewStory[15814:907] Name:Oliver
2013-02-24 17:37:22.629 TableViewStory[15814:907] this is completecount: 1
2013-02-24 17:37:22.630 TableViewStory[15814:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 17:37:22.631 TableViewStory[15814:907] Name:Rupert
2013-02-24 17:37:22.632 TableViewStory[15814:907] this is completecount: 2
2013-02-24 17:37:22.633 TableViewStory[15814:907] this is stickcount: 0
```

Removing the where clause completely:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Children"];
```

outcome:

```
2013-02-24 17:38:42.698 TableViewStory[15829:907] This is the sticker count: 4
2013-02-24 17:38:42.699 TableViewStory[15829:907] This is the complete count: 0
2013-02-24 17:38:42.700 TableViewStory[15829:907] Name:Oliver
2013-02-24 17:38:42.701 TableViewStory[15829:907] this is completecount: 1
2013-02-24 17:38:42.702 TableViewStory[15829:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 17:38:42.703 TableViewStory[15829:907] Name:Rupert
2013-02-24 17:38:42.704 TableViewStory[15829:907] this is completecount: 2
2013-02-24 17:38:42.705 TableViewStory[15829:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 17:38:42.707 TableViewStory[15829:907] Name:Emily
2013-02-24 17:38:42.708 TableViewStory[15829:907] this is completecount: 0
2013-02-24 17:38:42.709 TableViewStory[15829:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 17:38:42.710 TableViewStory[15829:907] Name:Stuart
2013-02-24 17:38:42.711 TableViewStory[15829:907] this is completecount: 0
2013-02-24 17:38:42.712 TableViewStory[15829:907] this is stickcount: 4
```

Putting brackets on statements:

```
  NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Children WHERE (Completed > %d) OR (Completed = %d AND 'Current Stickers' > %d)",completecount,completecount, stickercount];
```

This is outcome:

```
2013-02-24 17:59:33.987 TableViewStory[15898:907] This is the sticker count: 4
2013-02-24 17:59:33.988 TableViewStory[15898:907] This is the complete count: 0
2013-02-24 17:59:33.990 TableViewStory[15898:907] Name:Oliver
2013-02-24 17:59:33.991 TableViewStory[15898:907] this is completecount: 1
2013-02-24 17:59:33.992 TableViewStory[15898:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 17:59:33.993 TableViewStory[15898:907] Name:Rupert
2013-02-24 17:59:33.994 TableViewStory[15898:907] this is completecount: 2
2013-02-24 17:59:33.995 TableViewStory[15898:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 17:59:33.996 TableViewStory[15898:907] Name:Emily
2013-02-24 17:59:33.997 TableViewStory[15898:907] this is completecount: 0
2013-02-24 17:59:33.998 TableViewStory[15898:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 17:59:33.999 TableViewStory[15898:907] Name:Stuart
2013-02-24 17:59:34.000 TableViewStory[15898:907] this is completecount: 0
2013-02-24 17:59:34.002 TableViewStory[15898:907] this is stickcount: 4
```

now trying current stickers >:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Children WHERE 'Current Stickers' > %d",stickercount];
```

result with stuart:

```
2013-02-24 18:05:27.855 TableViewStory[15942:907] This is the sticker count: 4
2013-02-24 18:05:27.856 TableViewStory[15942:907] This is the complete count: 0
2013-02-24 18:05:27.857 TableViewStory[15942:907] Name:Oliver
2013-02-24 18:05:27.858 TableViewStory[15942:907] this is completecount: 1
2013-02-24 18:05:27.860 TableViewStory[15942:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 18:05:27.861 TableViewStory[15942:907] Name:Rupert
2013-02-24 18:05:27.862 TableViewStory[15942:907] this is completecount: 2
2013-02-24 18:05:27.863 TableViewStory[15942:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 18:05:27.864 TableViewStory[15942:907] Name:Emily
2013-02-24 18:05:27.865 TableViewStory[15942:907] this is completecount: 0
2013-02-24 18:05:27.866 TableViewStory[15942:907] this is stickcount: 0
2013-02-24 18:05:27.867 TableViewStory[15942:907] Name:Stuart
2013-02-24 18:05:27.868 TableViewStory[15942:907] this is completecount: 0
2013-02-24 18:05:27.870 TableViewStory[15942:907] this is stickcount: 4
```

This makes me think that its something wrong with stickcount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error might be that you're using quotations for numbers. Remove quotation marks around your parameters.

Thus instead of `Completed > '%d'` use `Completed > %d` (and of course the other params too)

When you use quotation marks, it most probably converts your string to a number which would explain why you have unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Changed the code to this : SELECT * FROM Children WHERE Completed > %d OR ( Completed = %d AND 'Current Stickers' > %d) - unfortunately, it made no difference :(

Comment: Didn't realise, you should also use sqlite3_column_int for your int parameters. Using sqlite3_column_text, you're forcing them to be strings I assume

Comment: Yeah you're right.  I'll change them up now, but the error persists.

Comment: Overall your code looks fine to me, one thing that I wasn't clear about: you have two columns 'complete' and 'completed'. You're querying against 'completed' but printing 'complete' in your log?

Comment: complete is treated like a boolean, representing if its actually complete(1,0) completed shows the amount of times it has been completed.  Yeah sorry for the confusion, its actually usually field 8 which is completed, but in the NSLOG i said complete.

Comment: Hmm, then I'd suggest several things: First remove the WHERE clause from your query to see the result, then remove one part of the WHERE clause to see the result, similarly remove the other part.

Comment: Okay done what you said.  Updated main question, check it out (Y)

Comment: the variable you pass into your query 'completecount' must be 0. That would explain these results

Comment: Yes, Stuart hasn't completed at all, it says this at the start of the log.  Emily hasn't either, thats why they are not displayed in the first query i made from your request.  Also btw, its 4 on stuart now, i did something to cause the increment.  Sorry if this confused you

Comment: Sorry I thought you had a more general issue. Looking at the results closely now, your query seems correct to me and it's odd that Emily and Stuart appear. Try putting the first part of the WHERE clause in brackets as well - so WHERE (Completed > %d) OR (...) .If this doesn't work could you print WHERE 'Current Stickers ' = %d

Comment: You have a trail now, print that whole SQL statement to ensure it's populated correctly. If not, trace why the sticker count variable is wrong

Comment: Your 'stickercount' variable is a negative number OR what you're printing doesn't correspond to actual columns. For the first possibility, log 'stickercount' right before you pass it to NSString for your SQL query. For the second possibility, instead of 8th and 10th columns, print each column for each row

Comment: Right.  Its a weird error, but i reloaded the database and it seemed to work.  And i changed the Current Stickers to Current_Stickers, which i should of done in the beginning, but it all works now.  I could of sworn i did this at least 3 times :( wasted so much time on this.  Sigh, appreciate your dedication for answering the questions.  So i'll give the correct answer for it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found the problem now. 'Current Stickers' is merely a string, and when you do 'bla bla' > 5, it converts the string to a number and produces YES or NO. Hence your unexpected results.